# Cannot read property 'forEach'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've got a problem with nodejs script 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Part of code

```js
var API_KEY = '481------------------bae55a0';

var totp = new TOTP('6------UCWLJOL');

var code = totp.now();

var prices;
request('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_all_item_prices/?api_key='+API_KEY+'&code='+code+'', function(error, response, body) {
prices = JSON.parse(body);
var newprice = JSON.parse('{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1464567644,"items":{}}}');
 
 prices.forEach(function (item) {
  newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
   "value": item.price*1000
  }
 });

    fs.writeFileSync('/var/www/prices.txt', JSON.stringify(newprice));
    logger.trace('New prices loaded');
});
```

Comment: post the part of the json that you get from API

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `prices.prices` is `undefined`, so it isn't an array. Why it is `undefined` and why you expect it to be something else, we can't know.

Comment: Also, you are using javascript. Why do `JSON.parse('{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1464567644,"items":{}}}');` when you can do `var newprice = {"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1464567644,"items":{}}};`

Comment: @Wojtek  Start Firefox and use the DeveloperTool->Network to see what response you got from the server. If you got something post it here

Comment: @MaxZoom: This is clearly Node code, not browser code. But yes, using a debugger is the right thing. Node has one built in now (which uses Chrome/Chromium as its UI).

Answer (score -3):

if `forEach` is undefined, it's because value `prices.prices` doesn't exist. Remember, if the value prices is the array, you just should up a lever, you don't need `prices.prices`, just

```
prices.forEach(function (item) {
        newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
            "value": item.price*1000
        }
```

But, if value `prices` has too many array objects inside, you have to choose the object using bracket notation.

```
prices[index].forEach(function (item) {
        newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
            "value": item.price*1000
        }
```

Comment: `prices = JSON.parse(body);` this is not working, I mean, when you tried to convert the body of the request in a js object, it takes as undefined. Can you show the  `request` method??